# New Order RSS Authentication Failure

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, rss

I have activated the new order rss feed via my Magento config.  However when trying to access the feed (`https://domain.com/rss/order/new/`) a login prompt asks for user and password.  After some searching this is supposed to be the same username as password as the admin, however my credentials do not work, and I am trying to access with an admin login with full permissions.

In order to make sure the RSS is working I disabled the authentication in the controller and the RSS now works fine but obviously this is not an ideal solution.

Any ideas as to why my admin login is not working or how to setup proper credentials that can easily access the new order RSS?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new user and new user role. Only give access to sales and catalog, then use these credentials to access your feeds.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/347541/prototype-js-conflict-with-google-one-tap-js-liabrary-in-magento-1-7-2.  Getting error while doing one tap sign in pls check any idea